Randomly shard large CSV into smaller CSVs
I am aiming to shuffle a csv file too large to load into the RAM of my device at once. My plan was to use csv.DictReader to go through the entire file and write each line randomly into one of a set of smaller files using csv.DictWriter, then shuffle all the smaller files, and then concatenate them again. I cannot however get past the first step, since the smaller files cannot be opened with pandas because it gives the following error: pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file.
To perform the first step, I made a list of csv DictWriter files, one for each small file I want to split the main file into, in order to randomly assign each line of the main file to one of the DictWriter files. Here is a dummy example that illustrates the idea of the first step, but on a synthetically generated csv file, which gives the same error:
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

#First, creating a dummy file just containing integers 0-19 over 2 columns.

data=pd.DataFrame({'col1':list(range(10)),'col2':list(range(10,20))})
data.to_csv('test_file.csv',index=False)

n_chunks=2 #For this example I only split the dummy file into two smaller files

#Next, make a list of DictWriter objects, one for each smaller file
file_names=[f"test_batch_{batch_no}.csv" for batch_no in list(range(n_chunks))]
chunks=[csv.DictWriter(open(file_name,'w'),["col1","col2"]) for file_name in file_names]

#Make headers for each smaller file
for chunk in chunks:
    chunk.writeheader()

#Now, randomly assign each line in test_file.csv to one of the smaller files.
with open("test_file.csv",newline='') as data:
    reader=csv.DictReader(data)
    for line in reader:
        i=random.randint(0,n_chunks-1)
        chunks[i].writerow(line)

for file_name in file_names:
#The next line gives the error.
    chunk=pd.read_csv(file_name)

What is strange is that the smaller files are composed entirely of lines directly copied from the main file, which in this example was itself created as a pandas file and can be loaded as a pandas dataframe without any problems. Moreover, when I inspect both of the smaller files that are created ('test_batch_0.csv' and 'test_batch_1.csv') in e.g. notepad, they look like regular csv files to me, but still somehow pd.read_csv cannot read it.
I tried to vary the newline parameters for the 'open' commands, since I found in previous posts that the 'No columns to parse form file' is sometimes caused by incorrect newlines, but to no avail.
For completeness, here is the full error path:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    chunk=pd.read_csv(file_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1026, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 620, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1620, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...]/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1898, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "[...].venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "parsers.pyx", line 581, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file


Many thanks in advance!

Do you require a solution that uses pandas?

@JonSG Preferably yes, because I think I will need to use pandas methods for further processing of the data.

Can you add some example CSV files?

That duplicate isn't correct for this case.  The problem was not closing and flushing the output files before reading them.

The original open files weren't closed so the changes weren't flushed to the file before reading.  Here's the fixed code with minor changes:
import pandas as pd
import random
import csv

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list(range(10)), 'col2': list(range(10, 20))})
data.to_csv('test_file.csv', index=False)

n_chunks = 2
file_names = [f'test_batch_{batch_no}.csv' for batch_no in range(n_chunks)]
# Open files
files = [open(file_name, 'w') for file_name in file_names]
# use files
chunks = [csv.DictWriter(file, ['col1', 'col2']) for file in files]

for chunk in chunks:
    chunk.writeheader()

with open('test_file.csv', newline='') as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data)
    for line in reader:
        random.choice(chunks).writerow(line)

# close files
for file in files:
    file.close()

for file_name in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print(df)

Sample output:
   col1  col2
0     0    10
1     1    11
2     2    12
3     6    16
   col1  col2
0     3    13
1     4    14
2     5    15
3     7    17
4     8    18
5     9    19


To preprocess the larger file and shard it into smaller files randomly, you can use DictReader and DictWriter, and then make sure you close your output files to flush any buffered writes:
import csv
import random

from io import TextIOWrapper

N = 10                           # the number of sharded output CSVs
OUT_NAME = "output_{i:0>3}.csv"  # pad the file's number with up to three zeroes

out_files: list[TextIOWrapper] = []  # the output file handles; hold on to these for closing
writers: list[csv.DictWriter] = []   # randomly select a DictWriter in the read-loop

for i in range(N):
    f_out = open(OUT_NAME.format(i=i), "w", newline="")
    out_files.append(f_out)

    w = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=["Col_1", "Col_2"], extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    writers.append(w)


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    for row in reader:
        w = random.choice(writers)
        w.writerow(row)


for f_out in out_files:
    f_out.close()

I created a sample input CSV that was 620MB in size (1_000_000 rows by 100 columns) and ran that program on it, and ended up with 10 files each about 1.3MB in size (only picking 2 out of 100 columns):
137K Nov 17 21:37 output_000.csv
138K Nov 17 21:37 output_001.csv
...  ...          ...
138K Nov 17 21:37 output_008.csv
134K Nov 17 21:37 output_009.csv

Creating 10 files barely used any memory above and beyond what the Python runtime requires (8MB on my machine). Sharding into more, smaller, files required more memory; I assume because each file has a buffer, so more buffers holding onto to rows before getting flushed to disk:



# ouput files
Memory used (MB)




10
8


100
15


1000
68




Well, as far as assigning each row of a large csv to a random destination file with headers and as long as you are not going to keep "too many" files open then I would leverage contextlib.ExitStack() and a dictionary of files to write to.
I not sure what "too many" open files is, but I have certainly used code like this to write to a dozen files probably more.
once the files are populated and potentially after shuffling their rows then you might be able to reload them into pandas to do whatever additional manipulation you like.
import csv
import random
import contextlib

TARGET_FILE_COUNT = 10
writers = {}
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    reader = csv.reader(stack.enter_context(open("in.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8")))
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        target_file_id = random.randrange(0, TARGET_FILE_COUNT)

        if target_file_id not in writers:
            writers[target_file_id] = csv.writer(stack.enter_context(open(f"out_{target_file_id}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="")))
            writers[target_file_id].writerow(headers)

        writers[target_file_id].writerow(row)


Hi. I wrote a solution that adds writers (and their underlying files) to a list, and I didn't bother with context or closing for this stand-alone program. My program runs about 4 seconds faster than yours. It seems like the only significant difference between the programs that would contribute to the runtime is contextlib. Do you see something else, or know why contextlib would matter?

@ZachYoung One thing I think might be an optimization on your part is that you pre-create the writers and thus bring that test out of the loop. I think you could still use a context manager if you wanted. Probably your strategy of pre-creating the writers is better anyways,
